# Reference Error: Navigator is not defined, when initialize Firebase Cloud Messaging in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have the Next JS website. I want to use a cloud messaging service so I import getMessaging. I think the issue is that initially, window is not available on the server side so maybe any conditions may help to resolve this issue

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
export const messaging = getMessaging(app);
```

[image]

I am trying to use the `cloud messaging` service of **Firebase** from the fronted side in **Next JS**
Please suggest any condition or something else that help me. I really appreciate any help you can provide.